# Using sbt-assembly for Newman, StackMob’s Http Client library

Tags: android, sbt, stackmob, sbt-assembly

I need to use [Newman, StackMob’s Http Client](https://github.com/stackmob/newman) library in my Android project.

I use `sbt-assembly` to generate one single (uber)jar with all dependencies. The command gives me a very big jar file (48mb) and Android can't convert it to dex.

How can I add only needed dependencies to my jar library?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the entire section in sbt-assembly's README on [excluding JARs and files](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-jars-and-files).

When you say:

> How can i add only needed dependencies to my jar library?

The word "dependencies" in context of `sbt-assembly` usually means dependent jars. The problem is at the jar level, you'd need all of them. What you have to do is find out `*.class` files that are not being used and exclude that out of the final fat jar. `sbt-assembly` does have merge strategy which you can use to ignore files.

For Android development however, because there are so many files to exclude, you'd need something that does the analysis automatically. That's where [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) comes in. This will make the resulting jar much smaller. But it is also a bit of a voodoo, since you might not be able to know if you need certain class or not for sure. Try [pfn/android-sdk-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin) if you haven't yet. It caches ProGuard result and makes it much faster.

Comment: thx for answer, i'll try it
one more problem is that by using sbt assembly, it add to my fat jar all dependencies and one more scala library, i saw a lot of examples ow to exlude adding scala into jar but no one help me who can explain me how to do that

Comment: excluding scala lib from our fat jar gives bad results, so now i'am trying to configurate and use ProGuard